# How to put a string at the bottom of the page? If I use \vfill it doesn't work quite right

Tags: formatting

I need to have a text at a very bottom of the page, but when I use \vfill the text goes a line or two above the bottom margin. I guess it has something to do with \maketitle. I use it, so that the first page would not be numerated, but I guess the numbering still holds, and so I cannot overwrite the absent number of the page.
Here is the reproducible example:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\date{}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{babel,etoolbox, lineno}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=ext-numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{name.bib}
\usepackage{color}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{\textcolor{green}{\bibopenbracket}}{\textcolor{green}{\bibclosebracket}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,graphicx, amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.:}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents}
\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
 

\begin{document}
\captionsetup{textfont={sf,sansmath, tiny}, labelfont = {footnotesize, bf,sf}}

\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large{UNIVERSITY}\\[-0.9ex]
\large{FACULTY}\\[-0.9ex]
\large{DEPARTMENT}\\[+15ex]
\end{center}



\begin{center}
\large{\textbf{THE TITLE OF THE THESES}}\\[+0.9ex]
\normalsize{\textbf{BSA}}\\[+15ex]
\end{center}



\vfill
\begin{center}
LONDON 2022
\end{center}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `centre` environment introduces some vertical space, so that LONDON 2022 is raised above the foot of the page. However, I don't understand how you expect items at the foot of the page to affect page numbering. Perhaps you could clarify that part of your question.

Comment: You can overlap the footer from the bottom of the page using `\raisebox{-\footskip}[0pt][0pt]{...}`, using tikzpagenodes with `\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[anchor=base] at (current page footer area.south) {...}`,  or at shipout using `\AddToHook{shipout/backgroun}{\put (...) ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

The body text of a document is set within a textblock space defined by `\textwidth` and `\textheight`. Above and below this are headers and footers which typically include page numbers and/or divisional (chapter/section) titles.

It seems that you do not want your  "LONDON 2022" to be within the textblock but below it where page numbers are often placed.

Use the `\fancyhdr` package to put centered text on your title page instead of a page number. The following is a stripped down version of your MWE eliminating packages that have no relationship to your problem but including `fancyhdr` code putting `LONDON 2022` centered at the bottom of your page.

```
% bottomlineprob.tex  SE 620539

    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\fancypagestyle{title}
\fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot[L,R]{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{LONDON 2022}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{center}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\thispagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{title}
\large{UNIVERSITY}\\[-0.9ex]
\large{FACULTY}\\[-0.9ex]
\large{DEPARTMENT}\\[+15ex]
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\large{\textbf{THE TITLE OF THE THESES}}\\[+0.9ex]
\normalsize{\textbf{BSA}}\\[+15ex]
\end{center}
\newpage
% \setcounter{page}{1} % uncomment this if this page is to be numbered 1

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}

\vfill
\begin{center}
LONDON 2022
\end{center}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]